# WPF: is it possible to have a content container move 3d dimenisional in a modelvisual3d element?

Tags: wpf, animation, 3d

i was learning 3d animation in wpf.. and most tutorials would make an image 3d then play with it alittle ..moving and changing dimensions..

so it got me wondering.. is it possible to add some type of data container (like a grid canvas.. or whatever).. and make it move in  3d dimensons too ?

i am not talking about skewing.. i am talking about real 3d movement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a lot of examples do in .Net3.0 is use visual brush to draw the visual of the control/data container on a surface in 3D space. And then map the mouse and keyboard events back to the 2D control (through a translation).

They are a lot of examples that illustrate this. (one for instance [is](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Shattering_Content___.aspx))

An alternative is to use a panel that layouts your control in 3D space using one of the [thriple opensource project](http://thriple.codeplex.com/) Or you could read the code (since it's opensource) as a starting point.